# Does $W \oplus U$, for a particular $W$ and $U$, equal $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Trying to teach myself some linear algebra before I even start the class, but I am a bit stuck. I have a question and honestly I don't know where to start. I'll be glad to get an answer but more important a good explanation.
By the way it's the first time I am asking a question here, so I am very sorry if I'm not following the rules.

Here is the question:

$$U = \{(x,y,z,t) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x+5y+4z+t = 0 \land y+2z+t=0\}$$

$$W = \{(x,y,z,t) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x+z+3t = 0 \land 2x-3y-4z+3t=0\}$$

Does $W \oplus U$ equal $\mathbb{R}^4$ (where the "+" sign is inside a circle, but it doesn't say what it means)?

Thank you very much; if the question is not written properly, please let me know.

Comment: The symbol $\oplus$ stands for [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules) (of vector spaces, in this case). Basically, that means that you can uniquely write every vector in $\Bbb{R}^4$ as a sum of a vector in $W$ and a vector in $U$.

Comment: Specifically, the internal direct sum in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, how do you type special symbols like that unique + sign?

Comment: click the edit and you can see the code I put in. If you can't do that see http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html just write it in there it'll find the LaTeX code for you.

Comment: You can also have a look at our [mathjax quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol $\oplus$ stands for [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules) (of vector spaces, in this case). Basically, the question is: *can you write every vector in $\Bbb{R}^4$ as a sum of a (unique) vector in $W$ and a (unique) vector in $U$*?

Note that the answer is positive if and only if you can find a basis of $\Bbb{R}^4$ formed by vectors in $U$ and vectors in $W$. Since $U$ and $W$ have dimension $2$, this amounts to finding vectors $u_1,u_2 \in U$ and $w_1,w_2 \in W$ such that $u_1,u_2,w_1,w_2$ are linearly independent.

---

A vector $(x,y,z,t)$ is in $U$ if and only if
$$
\begin{cases}
x+5y+4z+t = 0 \\
y+2z+t = 0
\end{cases}
\leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x = -4y -2z \\
t = -y -2z
\end{cases}
$$
in particular, every vector in $U$ is of the form $a u_1 + b u_2$ with
$$
u_1 =
\begin{pmatrix}
-4 \\
1 \\
0 \\
-1
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
u_2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 \\
0 \\
1 \\
-2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Similarly, a vector $(x,y,z,t)$ is in $W$ if and only if
$$
\begin{cases}
x+z+3t = 0 \\
2x−3y−4z+3t = 0
\end{cases}
\leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x = 3y +5z \\
t = -y -2z
\end{cases}
$$
in particular, every vector in $W$ is of the form $a w_1 + b w_2$ with
$$
w_1 =
\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\
1 \\
0 \\
-1
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
w_2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
5 \\
0 \\
1 \\
-2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now, the quickest way to check if some vectors are linearly independent is to check if the determinant of the matrix which has those vectors as columns is non-zero. In our case, $u_1,u_2,w_1,w_2$ are linearly independent if and only if
$$
0 \neq \det
\begin{pmatrix}
-4 & -2 & 3 & 5\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
-1 & -2 & -1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which isn't possible, because the second, third, and fourth line are linearly dependent. In other words, this means that $U \oplus W \neq \Bbb{R}^4$.

On the other hand, you can prove that $u_1,u_2,w_1$ are linearly independent, which means that $U \oplus W$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Linearly independent mean that: 

        a1*u1 + a2*u2 + a3*w1 + a4*w2 = 0

can only exist if 

        a1=a2=a3=a4=0

Comment: Linearly independent means that you cannot write one vector as a sum of multiples of the others, for example that there are no $a,b,c \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $u_1 = a u_2 + b w_1 + c w_2$. Equivalently, you can show that each vector in the standard basis of $\Bbb{R}^4$, i.e. $(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)$ can be written as $a u_1 + b u_2 + c w_1 + d w_2$ for some $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you, ill try again, maybe i can do it.

Comment: @Gigalala: Yes, your definition of "linearly independent" is equivalent to the one given by A.P., (though with A.P.s formulation it is not immediately clear that the set $\{0\}$ is linearly dependent).

Comment: I found vectors 4 vectors from W and U (2 from each one, like you said), but i am having trouble showing that they are linearly independent.

Comment: I found u1= (1,0,-4,-1) and u2 =(0,1,-2,-2) and w1=(1,0,2,-1) and w2 = (0,1,5,3)

Comment: How did you find those vectors? Note that $u_1 \notin U$ because $2 \cdot (-4) - 1 \neq 0$, $u_2 \notin U$ because $1 + 2 \cdot (-2) - 2 \neq 0$, $w_1 \notin W$ because $2 \cdot 1 - 4 \cdot 2 + 3 \cdot (-1) \neq 0$, and $w_2 \notin W$ because $5 + 3 \cdot 3 \neq 0$.

Comment: sorry typos, u1 =(4,1,0,-1), u2 = (-2,0,1,-2), w1=(1,2,-1,0), w2=(0,5,3,1,)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, $U\bigoplus W$, represents the direct sum as they previously mentioned. The vector space $U+W = \{u+w:u\in U, w\in W\}$. When the sum is direct, (i.e, the $\bigoplus$ symbol is used, it means that $U\cap W = \emptyset$.

Now, going to the exercise, to see that $U\bigoplus W = \mathbb{R}^4$ you have to see that $\mathbb{R}^4 \subseteq U\bigoplus W$ and $U\bigoplus W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^4$. One of the inclusions is obvious. However the other is not. Try to prove it. (Watch out, this may be not true, as the exercise states, in this case you will have to find a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^4$ such that $v$ is not in $U\bigoplus W$).